# Minimum value in a range, with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, max

I have an Excel sheet:

```
A.                         B.                        C.   
X.                         I.                 10/10/2018 06:27:54    
X.                         I.                 12/10/2018 13:00:00
X.                         U.                 12/10/2018 13:01:20
Y.                         I.                 13/10/2018 13:05:40
Y.                         U                  15/10/2018 07:22:23
Y.                         U.                 17/10/2018 08:20:43
```

Column A is customer, Column B is activity, C is Start time.

How can get the maximum value (column C) of activity `I` for customer `X`?

Comment: What have you tried please? There are many examples of Max Ifs on SO. You may also be able to use a pivottable. Your title says minimum and question body says max - though same principle will apply.

Comment: use the following formula to determine if your date time values in C are actually numbers or strings representing a date. `=isnumber(C2)`  a result of true means its a number which means it will not need to be converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a standard formula that performs array like calculations

#### AGGREGATE

Use the following formula.  Since it performs array like calculations, avoid using full column references like F:F as it can lead to a lot of unnecessary calculations.

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,C1:C6/((A1:A6="X")*(B1:B6="I")),1)
```

Instead of hard coding your search values, you can set up the formula to search based on values in other cells.  I used the following formula in the example below:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,C1:C6/((A1:A6=$E2)*(B1:B6=$F2)),1)
```

[image]

This answer assumes that your date time in column C is stored as number.  If it is stored as a string it will need a modification to the formula in order to convert it to a numerical date for excel.

Comment: @ShivamShrivastava I would just add two comments on the `AGGREGATE` function : (1) hard to audit/understand, as the actual functionality is hidden behind codes/parameters (who knows without consulting the documentation that `14` means `LARGE` and `6` means `ignore errors`??) (2) that second parameter can either be useful, if you know there can be errors in the input data and you purposely want to ignore these, or dangerous, in particular for larger input data ranges, as it will give you no feedback on errors in the input data, so results might be unexpected/wrong without you knowing.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with an array formula (ctrl+shift+enter) :
`=MAX((--(A1:A6="X."))*(--(B1:B6="I."))*(C1:C6))`

Explanation:

- the `(A1:A6="X.")` results in an array with `TRUE/FALSE` values where the condition is met;
- the `--` converts this in `1/0`
- the first `*` (array multiplication) gives an array with `1/0` where both conditions are met;
- the second `*` gives an array with all values from column C that corresponds with the rows where both conditions are met;
- the `MAX` results then in the maximum.

Just a tricky part with the dot behind the X and I. Not sure whether this is part of your data, if not you of course have to modify the condition. And instead of hard coding it in the formula, much better to work with cell reference.

Answer (score 0):

No need for complex AGGREGATEs or nasty array formulas.

A nice, simple MAXIFS will do what you want:

```
=MAXIFS($C$2:$C$7,$A$2:$A$7,$E$2,$B$2:$B$7,$F$2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But MAXIFS function is not available in my excel version.